# How to use the map function in haskell?

Tags: dictionary, haskell

I'm trying to use map to return a list of lists.  But i keep getting an error.  I know map takes in a function and then uses that function.  But i keep getting an error on it.

```
map (take 3) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is supposed to return [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]], but it returns this error

```
<interactive>:6:1: error:
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a. Num [a] => [[a]]
```

is it hitting null is that why?

Comment: `map (take 3) (take 3 (tails [1,2,3,4,5]))`

Comment: wait, what's going on here? and this returns the same error

Comment: `map` only passes one item at a time to each call of the mapping function, not a sublist. My code uses `tails` followed by `take 3` in order to get the first 3 sublists.

Comment: it still results as an error

Comment: [It works for me](https://ideone.com/Jsa368).

Comment: BTW, Haskell's error messages are weird which maybe daunting for beginner, you need to either devote your time into this old language which is said to be underrated (I think its getting overrated now) which practically will hinder your productivity(those hard to understand error messages), keep going deeper into the language and you will find it easier to debug. Switching to another easier language would boost your productivity without a doubt!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at exactly what the error message is saying.

```
map (take 3) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`map`'s type signature is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So it takes a function from `a` to `b` and returns a function from `[a]` to `[b]`. In your case, the function is `take 3`, which takes a list and returns a list. So `a` and `b` are both `[t]`. Therefore, the second argument to `map` should be `[[t]]`, a list of lists. Now, Haskell looks at the second argument and sees that it's a list of numbers. So it says "How can I make a number into a list?" Haskell doesn't know of any good way to do that, so it complains that it doesn't know any type `Num [t]`.

Now, as for what you meant to do, I believe it was mentioned in the comments. The `tails` function<sup>1</sup> takes a list and returns the list of all tails of that list. So

```
tails [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-- ==> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5], [5], []]
```

Now you can apply the `take` function to each argument.

```
map (take 3) (tails [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
-- ==> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5], [5], []]
```

Oops! We've got some extra values we don't want. We only want the values that have three elements in them. So let's *filter* out the ones we don't want. `filter` takes a predicate (which is just a fancy way of saying "a function that returns a Boolean) and a list and returns a list containing only the elements that satisfy the predicate. The predicate we want is one that takes a list and returns whether or not that list has three elements.

```
\x -> ...           -- We want only the lists
\x -> length x ...  -- whose length
\x -> length x == 3 -- is exactly equal to 3
```

So that's our function. Now we pass that to `filter`.

```
filter (\x -> length x == 3) (map (take 3) (tails [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
-- ==> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

---

[1] Note that you may need to `import Data.List` to get the `tails` function.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: Filtering like that is much slower than just using `take 3` again as 4castle suggested.